# What is the difference between Input signal and input voltage?

Tags: oscillator

In our oscillator chapter in barkhausen criterion I have read if MvAv=1 then it will create undamped oscillations even without any input signal. It added that" then only if we put small input voltage it will create oscillations". I found the two words contradictory. They seem to cancel each other. My question is if you say there is no need of any input signal why need input voltage?? What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not contradictory. "Input signal" is a general term while "input voltage" is a specific term.

In electronic circuits, electric attributes carry information while in electrical circuits they carry energy. Both voltage and current can be used as input signals. So "input current" is another form of "input signal".

For some reasons, we prefer using voltage than current as an input signal. Current interface is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

the  circuit will have thermal noise.

A 100Kohm resistor plus 10pf cap is 1uS time constant. the is 160KHz f3db bandwidth, and if integrated out to infinity, produces 20 microvolts rms random noise.

Amusingly, a 10Kohm resistor and 10pf has lower noise density but higher bandwidth. And if integrated out to infinity, also has 20 microvolt rms noise.